# When in Tritium, how do I select a div containing more than one class?

Tags: class, html, moovweb, tritium

I forget how to do this in the Moovweb SDK

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this is your HTML:

```
<div class="foo bar"></div>
```

You can use the XPath `contains()` function:

```
$("div[contains(@class, 'foo')]") {
  # More Tritium here...
}
```